# Angular Material Progress bar not working - produces dotted lines

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular-material

I am trying to create a contact form in Angular and I wish to display an indeterminate progress bar using Angular Material when the user clicks on submit.

I followed the steps mentioned on the official Angular Material site (https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview). However, when I include it in my web application, the progress bar simply shows up as dotted lines.

PFB screenshot displaying the issue:

[[image: UI Screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKIpQ.png)

Code Snippet:

[image: VS Code screenshot]

Can anyone please advise why does Angular-Material progress bar behave this way and the possible solutions for it?

Comment: What can possibly go wrong?! Just check if your own css is not conflicting with material design css. Also check your dependencies correctly & their versions. Check this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uozzn3?file=app/progress-bar-configurable-example.ts

Comment: add jsfiddle link

Answer (score 13):

Solved!
I had missed out on including the pre-built theme in the root css file.

Adding `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` in style.css resolved the issue and the progress bar started working as expected.

Comment: To get the progress bar working for a custom theme, you must @include it in your global scss file: `@include mat-progress-bar-theme($app-theme);`

Comment: A better way would be to just `@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);` which should apply the custom theme globally.